# Not able to send e-mail using MUTT

Tags: email, mutt

I have set the `from: email-id` in `.muttrc`. I am using the following command to send an e-mail from command-line:

```
echo "<html><body><b>BOLD</b></body></html>" | mutt -e "set content_type=text/html" -s "HTML"  -- xyz@gmail.com
```

I am able to send e-mail from only my home internet. If I try to send from any other network, it doesn't go. How should I fix this to be able to send e-mail from any network? What all changes are supposed to be made?